# Translation from C++ to Python for pyqt

Tags: python, c++, pyqt

I am always struggling to get the Python equivalent when reading the Qt documentation or answers given on Stackoverflow in C++ for instance this one:

```
       QList<QStandardItem*> NewRow;
       QString age = pyt.value(0).toString();
       QStandardItem *newColumn = new QStandardItem(age);
       NewRow.append(newColumn);
       QString height = pyt.value(1).toString();
       newColumn = new QStandardItem(height);
```

My translation would be:

```
QStandardItem(NewRow)
age = pyt.value(0).toString()
#can't understand this line
NewRow.append(NewColumn)
height = pyt.value(1).toString()
newColumn = QStandardItem(height)
```

More broadly is there a doc somewhere which would explain the various equivalent between the 2 languages?

Comment: `newrow = []`
`age = pyt.value(0)`
`newcolumn = QStandardItem(age)`
`newrow.append(newcolumn)`
`height = pyt.value(1)`
`newcolumn = QStandardItem(height)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of such a document, but I think the main thing for you to understand is that C++ is statically typed, so variables must be declared before they can be used and this follows the form:

*type* *variableName*;

If you see a `*` or `&` in the type, that's a pointer or reference, respectively, so just ignore it for this purpose.  These forms:

```
Type variable("argument");
Type variable = Type("argument");
Type* variable = new Type("argument");
```

Declare and instantiate variables.  Translate them by calling the constructor:

```
variable = Type("argument")
```

Later uses won't have the type first, but translate them the same.  In your example `newColumn` creates one object at the declaration (type given) and another near the end (no type given).

If you see this:

```
variable.foo;   // non-pointer
variable->foo;  // pointer
```

In Python just use the dot form:

```
variable.foo
```

C++ has a difference between pointers and values, so you can usually ignore `*` or `&` in the *use* of the variable, e.g. `function(*variable)` or `function(&variable)` in C++ will likely just be `function(variable)` in Python.

The last wrinkle in this example is when you have `<>` in the type.  Those are C++ templates and there is no direct equivalent in Python.  Instead they will either give a fixed name for the whole type or let you use an alternate Python type instead.  In this example it looks like they accept Python `list` objects rather than having a special name for `QList<QStandardItem*>`. Don't be thrown off by the unconventional naming of `NewRow` in your example, that is the variable name and not a type.

Unfortunately QT uses a lot of preprocessor macros in the native code, which are by convention written in all-caps, like `Q_OBJECT`, `SIGNAL`, `SLOT`, etc.  There is no general rule for translating these but many can just be ignored.

Comment: Thank you very much Jake, this is exactly what I needed to help me thru the sometimes difficult Qt C++ "dialect"